# Skin of Large, Terrestrial Amphibians

Tags: creature-design, climate, fauna

I have some large, megafauna level amphibians inhabiting a temperate rainforest with naturally high levels of humidity. Would my large amphibians have any problems maintaining a classic amphibian type of skin (smooth & slimy) or would they need skin for akin to reptilian scales?

Thanks! (Ignore circulatory, Skeletal, and Respiratory problems that come with large amphibians)

Answer (score 3):

In a rainforest with high relative humidity "normal" amphibian adaptations can work. If their environment ever dries out properly they'll need to get into pools or the like in a hurry though. Temperate Rainforests tend to have a dry-ish season unlike their tropical counterparts which are wet all year around. During those times you'll need refuge habitat in the form of wetlands or open water where they can wait out the dry months.

Answer (score 3):

So long as the humidity is high enough, nope, they shouldn't have any problems with skin. In fact, larger amphibians ought to have an easier time, since they'll have a larger volume per unit surface area in which to store water, so they will lose it through their skin proportionately more slowly than a smaller creature.